# What is this old US Air Force plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, us-air-force

What model of plane is visible in this image?
[image]

Comment: Where is the aircraft in the picture located?

Comment: @nexus_2006 probably Kelly AFB. It was on display there for years (1957-2004).  Sadly, I didn't go see it in time.

Comment: The early versions of the B36 had 6 pusher propellers. Later versions added a pod with 2 jet engines on each wing. This led to the phrase "6 turning, 4 burning".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Based on the unique 6x pusher-prop configuration, this looks like a derivative of the Convair B-36 Peacemaker. Looking up the Wikipedia article for the B-36 and scrolling down to the [variants section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker#Related_models), this seems like an [XC-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_XC-99) (or, more aptly, *the* XC-99):

[image]

*Public domain image via United States Air Force - USAF photo via, Joaobsen, Wagner, Greer (1980), B-36 Peacemaker in action - Aircraft No. 42, Squadron/Signal Publications; 1st edition, ISBN-10: 0897471016*

This was to be a passenger variant of the airframe, with a passenger capacity of up to 400 people. Beyond the prototype, it didn't enter service.

Comment: Interestingly, the B-36 was involved in the first [Broken Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_British_Columbia_B-36_crash) incident where three of its six piston engines caught fire off the coast of British Columbia.

Comment: "seems like  ̶a̶n̶ *the* XC-99:"  ...ftfy ;)

Comment: @coconaut if you're interested in other B-36 trivia, there was also a variant, the [NB-36H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_NB-36H), powered by a nuclear generator which was supposed to combine the endurance of a nuclear submarine with the airworthiness of something that's distinctly not a nuclear submarine.

Comment: When I was a boy in Sacramento, CA circa 1955, a C-99 regularly came into McClellan AFB.

Answer (score -2):

XC-99, o e was built and was on display for years at Kelly AFB, Texas and later moved to the Air Force Museum.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/42233)

Comment: @RalphJ The information in this answer is correct and does provide an answer to the question. The only problem is it doesn't provide info that wasn't in the other answer already.